# Power Query: how to add columns for each row in a list

Tags: merge, powerbi, addition, transpose, powerquery

I have a column with a series of elements in power bi as follows:
- an excel sheet called "list" with a series of letter
- an excel sheet called "columns to add" with a several columns and lines to add to each letters of my lists.

Here is an example of my "list" sheet:

```
  |---------------------|  
  |       Name          |  
  |---------------------|
  |         A           |    
  |---------------------|
  |         B           |     
  |---------------------|
  |         C           |    
  |---------------------|
  |        D            |
```

Here is an example of my "columns to add file":

```
                        |---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|   
                        |      Pro1           |     Pro2        |   Pro3       |      Pro4       | 
                        |---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
                        |         56          |     dgdt        |  gdro1       |     gggggro1    | 
                        |---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
                        |        56           |     dgdt        |  gdro1       |     gggggro1    | 
                        |---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
                        |        4            |    dgdt         |  gdro1       |     gggggro1    | 
                        |---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
                        |     4               |    4                  4                  4
```

And for each element, A, B...I am trying to add 4 columns which are in an other file.
I would have a result as follows for each letters:

```
  |---------------------|---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|   
  |       Name          |      Pro1           |     Pro2        |   Pro3       |      Pro4       | 
  |---------------------|---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
  |         A           |         56          |     dgdt        |  gdro1       |     gggggro1    | 
  |---------------------|---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
  |         A           |        56           |     dgdt        |  gdro1       |     gggggro1    | 
  |---------------------|---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
  |         A           |        4            |    dgdt         |  gdro1       |     gggggro1    | 
  |---------------------|---------------------|-----------------| -------------|-----------------|  
  |        A            |     4               |    4                  4                  4
```

So far, I have currently transposed my list, and repeated as many times as I would like to add columns.

Then I created an index for each table, and I merged them as a new query for all rows of both files.

But it does not work, I do not how to proceed.

So far I have the following M code for my column for which I need to add columns to each element:

```
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"       Name          ", type text}}),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type1"),
#"repeat Table" =   Table.Repeat(#"Transposed Table",4),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"repeat Table", "Index", 1, 1)
in
#"Added Index"
```

And the following m code for the columns in which I merge both of my file with an index that I added to each:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"columns to add", {"Index"}, list, {"Index"}, "list", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded list" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "list", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Index"}, {"list.Column1", "list.Column2", "list.Column3", "list.Column4", "list.Index"})
in
    #"Expanded list"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom column to each of the two tables, set to the number 1 for all rows

Merge one table with the other using the new column,  merge type **Full Outer (all rows from both)**

Expand and remove extra column

```
let Part1 = Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Custom", each 1),
Part2 = Table.AddColumn(Table2, "Custom", each 1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Part1,{"Custom"},Part2,{"Custom"},"Part2",JoinKind.FullOuter),
#"Expanded Part2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Part2", {"Pro1", "Pro2", "Pro3", "Pro4"}, {"Pro1", "Pro2", "Pro3", "Pro4"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Part2",{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

more generically for any number of columns

```
let Part1 = Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Custom", each 1),
Part2 = Table.AddColumn(Table2, "Custom", each 1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Part1,{"Custom"},Part2,{"Custom"},"Part2",JoinKind.FullOuter),
ColumnsToExpand = List.RemoveLastN(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Merged Queries", "Part2"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),1),
#"Expanded Part2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Part2",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand ),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Part2",{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Its works! It is great and depressing! I thought that I had a great idea with the transposition! I am really saddened not be better...well no it did not work actually...my letters are not here anymore, only the repetition....

Comment: I am sorry for not having accepted this a lot earlier!